# What does @code mean in Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

An example is here:

```
* An implementation of {@code goog.events.Listenable} with full W3C
* EventTarget-like support (capture/bubble mechanism,
```

https://developer.pubref.org/static/apidoc/global/closure/goog/events/EventTarget.html

I can guess what it means but where can I find its exact definition? I checked all the Google Closure Annotation docs but couldn't find. Thanks :)

Comment: I think @code is a Javadoc tag, basically meaning the text inside shouldn't be treated as HTML, but code block instead.  But in this instance I think it's just to make the text look different during documentation as goog.events.Listenable is fine in HTML.

Comment: Keith is correct, and should write an answer saying as much.  This might be code that was converted from Java to Javascript with these old Javadoc tags.  In more recent closure library code markdown is used for documentation, and the documentation is generated with  [Dossier](https://github.com/jleyba/js-dossier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated

Per my new understanding; Since JSDocs supports markdown. {@code FooBar} is therefore deprecated in favor of back-ticks `` `FooBar` ``.

## Old

You can see the output of the docs you've asked about on the [Closure API's documentation page for goog.events.EventTarget](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.events.EventTarget.html).

When the JSDocs are rendered the @code tag will cause the code with in brackets to be rendered with as a `<code></code>` element.

Source: [js-dossier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-dossier#the-code-and-literal-taglets)

There's also the much better documentation from the JavaDocs... docs:

**{@code  text}**

- Equivalent to `{@literal}`.
- Displays text in code font without interpreting the text as HTML markup or nested javadoc tags. This enables you to use regular angle brackets (< and >) instead of the HTML entities (< and >) in doc comments, such as in parameter types (), inequalities (3 < 4), or arrows (<-). For example, the doc comment text:

  ```
  {@code A<B>C}
  ```

  displays in the generated HTML page unchanged, as:

  ```
  A<B>C
  ```

  The noteworthy point is that the  is not interpreted as bold and is in code font.
  If you want the same functionality without the code font, use {@literal}.

Source: [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@code%7D)

Comment: Just as a followup, it's purely for documentation and has no special meaning to closure-compiler.