# Multi-line comments inside jsDoc code examples

Tags: jsdoc

How can we use a multi-line comment inside a jsDoc example?

I want to include the following code snippet:

```
/**
* @example
*
* a.setConnection(/* connection details here */);
*
*/
```

The engine does not seem to like such code at all. I have tried using HTML special symbols, like `&#43;* connection details here *&#43;`, but jsDoc does not convert them into proper symbols.

How can we make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does @code mean in Google Closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862968/what-does-code-mean-in-google-closure)

Comment: @GrahamPHeath No, it is not a duplicate, that question doesn't help with this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discovered on my own, special symbols are not supported in jsDoc inside `@example` block. They work only inside inline code blocks, like this:

````
```js
a.setConnection(&#47;* connection details here *&#47;);
```
````

outputs: `a.setConnection(/* connection details here */);`

But unlike `@example`, you cannot place an inline code block after everything, because it is inline, which means it will be somewhere before your `@returns` section.

Awkward, I know, but there is no other way.